# jQuery methods using unordered/optional arguments

Tags: jquery, arguments

There are a heap of jQuery methods that allow you to reorder or omit particular arguments. For example:

```
$('#box').animate({top: 100}, 2000, "linear", function(){alert("done");});
```

Works exactly the same as:

```
$('#box').animate({top: 100}, 2000, function(){alert("done");});
```

How does jQuery configure their methods to allow this flexibility without passing an associative array to a single argument?

Would they be checking the datatype of each argument and allocating it based on the result? Would this add substantial overhead for each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have emulated my own solution using a switch.

```
// Allocate passed arguments to settings based on type
for( var i = 0; i <= arguments.length; i++ ) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    switch ( typeof arg ) {
        case "function":
            settings.action = arg;
            break;
        case "boolean":
            settings.runOnLoad = arg;
            break;
        case "number":
            settings.duration = arg;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [jQuery.animate() function on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js) I see that they are calling jQuery.speed() with the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th parameters.  The speed function is defined a bit further down and does some type checking with the parameters.

Code snippet from effects.js:

```
jQuery.speed = function( speed, easing, fn ) {
    var opt = speed && typeof speed === "object" ? jQuery.extend( {}, speed ) : {
        complete: fn || !fn && easing ||
            jQuery.isFunction( speed ) && speed,
        duration: speed,
        easing: fn && easing || easing && !jQuery.isFunction( easing ) && easing
    };
    ...
};
```

Comment: Hrm. I guess that could be doing it... But I can't read it! :) DANG

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, they typically test if `$.isFunction`, `$.isObject` `$.isArray`, etc. and move around arguments based on what type they are. This really only works if you have a [predefined list of prototypes](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you're expected. (In animate's case the second argument could be an object (options) or a numeric value (duration).

Answer (score 0):

Sure jQuery use `if`, `else` and `switch` statement, every arguments must be checked first,
Is function, boolean, string, integer or object value

Before it can run.